# Mono for Android Release error

Tags: c#, android

I'm using Mono for Android (C#). I'm trying to get the .apk file using MonoDevelop, but when I set project for release (using this guide: [LINK](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Deployment,_Testing,_and_Metrics/publishing_an_application/Part_1_-_Preparing_an_Application_for_Release)) I get this Error:

> Error MSB4018: The "GenerateJavaStubs" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: /manifest/@package attribute MUST
>   contain a period ('.').    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ManifestDocument.Merge(List`1 subclasses, List`1
>   selectedWhitelistAssemblies, Boolean embed)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost
>   taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost
>   taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask,
>   Boolean& taskResult) (MSB4018)

Answer (score 0):

What does your package name look like? Android requires the package name to contain at least one dot.